# Pimefaces Password Autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces

My application is primefaces and java spring. System need to be login by entering username and password. After that it has form to fill some transaction details such as amount, account no etc.

My question is it has field to enter secret no(PIN). So I make it as a password field. but when i login to the system  the previous input field of the password field always filled with my username. I tried many ways to overcome this hassle. I used autoComplete = "off" as well. But it does not work.

Comment: I have added this before the password field. <p:inputText id="dummy" value="0" style="display:none" />. But the same thing happen.

Comment: Post your login form code.